# Django: Change the HTML button when user joins a event with ManyToMany field

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am designing a event management system using django. I have a problem in changing the button of html page. 
The problem is:

1.If user is not authenticated then the button should have the value "Login to join"
2. After login, if the user clicks the "join" button(which is earlier "login to join") then the same button changes to "Joined".
3. If the The number of joiners is exceeds to the given limit then the same button should replace with "Full" or "Not Available".

```
{% if user.is_authenticated  %}
 <a href="{{ event.increase_join }}"><button>Join Now</button></a>
 {% else %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login to Join match</a>
{% endif %}
```

I tried the above one but it is not capable to handle my problem

the views.py is given below:

```
@login_required
def event_joined(request,id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event,id=id,available=True)
    current_joiner = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    event.joiners.add(current_joiner)
    event.joined+=1
    event.available_slot-=1
    event.save()
    return render(request,'events/event/detail.html',{'event': event})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an *elif statement* like:

```
{% elif event.available_slot is None  %}
<button>Full</button>
```

Comment: okay, but what should i do to change the "join" into "joined"

Comment: After a user clicks the button join, do they still stay on the same page?

Comment: actually it is not decided yet, but yes, whenever the user go to the same page the 'join' option must reflected as 'joined', so that one user restricted to join the same event multiple times